# CRUD in orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms

Guys i am new to OrchardCMS. I've done alot in Asp.net with C# and having basic knowledge of MVC using entity framework.

Guys i am really Stuck With Orchard and cant understand the way of Work. i read the official documentation but it won't help Much. So Please Give me any

**Simple CRUD Operation in OrChard CMS????????**

with proper definations. ie where to add file and what does it do n all.

I searched before post it and no programmer yet answer this. So pls be the first one.

I am able to create static widget after following the documentation but stuck with Dynamic page. As far as i know the following steps:

- create module using codegen
- add modal with simple members with get set method
- create migration file using codegen

what to do next ie. how to render it in View and how to add view to page?
i've also see this https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/storing-non-content-data-in-orchard but didnt get how they set up all this. Help me to understand as simple as possible ie the url example.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: My code is very confusion cause i dont know the flow of Orchard. But if you still want then let me show you the screen in answer

Comment: That doesn't matter, just show us what you have tried. Please edit your question and put the code in code-tags.

Comment: You should first read up some tutorials and more documentation. Just follow some simple tutorials which will help you to understand the basics of Orchard, like [these](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules/)

Comment: i am reading it sir but it world be great help if i can see the flow, the simple 2 field crud operation. Code help me to understand faster instead theory but till then i am still reading.

Comment: Then read the code of [this module](https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Training-Demo-Module), which gives you a full description of the flow in code

Comment: This module does not contain solution file. How do i suppose to open this or any other way to run this project????

Comment: @Jatin this module isn't supposed to run. It's "just" a very good documentation of all the ins and out of an orchard module.

Comment: Actually the module can be run and you'll be able to use its demo features; you just need to put it in an Orchard solution. This was included in its documentation, but clarified it now. And BTW thanks @Xceno :-).